# How do I specify an order for layers (specifically shadows)?

Tags: html, css

I'd like for the shadow of the red part to be overlapping the white part, rather than vice-versa.

[image: Screencap of issue]

Applicable CSS:

```
#container { (the white part)
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto 24px auto;
  background: #FFFAFA; /*background: url(images/grid.png) center top no-repeat;*/
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 45px #343434;
}

#banner { (the red part)
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #BC4E4C 0%, #9E403F 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #BC4E4C 0%, #9E403F 100%);
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 10px #343434;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #612525;
}
```

In case it's important, the banner's before the main content in the HTML.  Thanks!

Comment: I suggest pasting the relevant HTML code rather than describing it in English, as HTML has an underestimated ability to speak for itself ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply adding `position: relative` to `#banner` should do it - a new ["stacking context"](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/stacking) will be created.

---

Just to be safe: you *might* also need `z-index: a number` if there are other elements not included in your question that you'd also like the shadow to appear on top of.

Comment: How is it even close to setting the layer order?

Comment: `z-index` won't work unless you change `position` from the initial value of `static`: you need `position: relative`. You don't need to set an explicit `z-index` to make something appear on top if nothing else is using `z-index`.

Comment: Or to put it another way: statically-positioned elements aren't layers.

Comment: Thanks, ThirtyDot.  While it didn't answer the question posed in the title, it _did_ solve the issue I was looking to fix.  Sorry for the poorly-worded title.

Answer (score 0):

Use css property `z-index`. Higher `z-index` means the element gets in front.

In your example add

```
#container {
  z-index: 1;
}
#banner {
  z-index: 2;
}
```

and it will work.

Comment: They will need something besides `position: static` for that to do anything.